# VisualStudio 2012 crashes on opening web-based project - Windows 7 - Windows error message

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, windows-7

Everything had beed working great, but suddenly something happened and every time I try to open any **web-based project** (either MVC or just 'Open Web Site', any others are just fine), Visual Studio **2012** crashes with Windows environment message:

---

### MyProject - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator): devenv.exe - System error

### Exception Processing Message 0xc0000005 Parameters 0x000007FEFD4A718C 0x000007FEFD4A718C 0x000007FEFD4A718C 0x000007FEFD4A718C

### ОК

I did not notice exact moment when it stopped working. And obviously I have different extensions etc. But I believe, I did not install any big soft these days.
I've installed Windows 8 though, but separatly - on separate volume to try it. Theoretically, it might affect my situation, but I don't know how is that possible - at least I don't know any explanations.

I've tried to **refresh Visual Studio 2012 installation**, even removed and installed it again.

However, at the same time, I have Visual Studio **2010** previously installed, and it opens web-based projects without any problems.

Mentioned error message above is, as I understand, some generic error message - googling did not help on its recognizing, so don't know what to do - don't really want to reinstall Windows because of that.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what was the cause of the problem, but after all other tries I've applied all pending updates of **Windows Update** service and everything works well after that.